# how javascript handles variables in objects?

Tags: javascript, object, variables

I have a question about declaring a variable in an object. Assuming that global or window is also an object, why is it not possible to declare a variable using let in an object that is a child of the window object? I do not understand that. Thanks for the answer and sorry for the English but I hope you understand the question.

this doesnt worked

```
let a = 'global';
console.log(a);
const outsideObj = {

    let b = 'outside var',
    logIt() {
        console.log(this);
        console.log(a);
        console.log(this.b)
    }
};

outsideObj.logIt();
```

this worked

```
console.log(this);

let a = 'global';
console.log(a);

const outsideObj = {

    b: 'outside var',
    logIt() {
        console.log(this);
        console.log(a);
        console.log(this.b)
    }
};

outsideObj.logIt();
```

i dont get difference between windows object and regular object why is it possible in parent and not in child?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please post your Sourcecode which shows us what you tried so far. Explain what you assume that will happen and show what actually happens. try to close that gap with your thougts as best as you can.

Comment: @David: shotgun ! :D

Comment: Having said that... What you're asking about is just the syntax for object literals.  When you define an object literal, you're not "creating variables in the object".  You're specifying the properties of that object.

Comment: @David but if this is true why you can create variable in global object when it is object too ?

Comment: @sai-monSVK: The global context doesn't take place *within an object literal declaration* for the `window` object.  The two are separate concepts entirely.  Assigning a value to a variable which hasn't been declared treats that "variable" as a property on the `window` object.  That's all.  It's not some trick about object declaration syntax.

Comment: The global object is a special case -- global variables are automatically turned into properties of the global object. But this doesn't generalize to other contexts. The top-level code is not an object literal.

Comment: @Barmar -- Thanks for answer.. In my opinion, it is not logical to treat two identical types, i.e. objects, differently, but I understood that the window object is a special object and it simply works differently in it and i have to get used to it.

Comment: JavaScript is a very quirky language because of the way the language interacts with browser contexts. It was not designed in a clean, orthogonal way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An object has properties and can be created by an object literal with property definitions.

A scope has variables and can be created by a block statement with variable declarations.

Do not mix these two concepts, especially not syntactically. That global `var` and `function` declarations implicitly create properties on the global object is  a special case, and also only works by the global object being provided by the runtime - there is no object literal for it.